# Breaking change: Mongoose 6.7.2 to 7.0.3 - no error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My project uses Mongoose as its ODM. Upgrading to 7.0.3 from 6.7.2 in the Express backend causes the controller function below to break, and I can't figure out why.

Imports are configured as follows:

```
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import Intervention from '../models/intervention.model.js'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
```

The breaking function is as follows:

```js
// @desc    Get single intervention
// @route   GET /api/interventions/:id
// @access  Protected
const getInterventionById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const oid = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
  const pipeline = [
    {
      $match: {
        _id: oid,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'students',
        localField: 'student_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'student',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$student',
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'campuses',
        localField: 'student.campus_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'campus',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$campus',
      },
    },
  ]

  try {
    const results = await Intervention.aggregate(pipeline)
    console.log(results)
    return res.json(results)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error(error.message)
  }
})
```

Despite logging everywhere I can think to do so, no error is logged. I've also reviewed the [Migration Guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html) but don't see any relevant changes.

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: There are no errors logged to the console. See where logging is attempted for further details.

Comment: how does it "break" at least?